# How to query an Elasticsearch based API with nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I need to query this API: https://docs.art.rmngp.fr/#search I have a react app where I was planning on making HTTP requests to this API but I haven't been able to perform a search.  My question is how to go about doing this? Do I need to make a server to query this API? or what the architecture would look like.

How would you query this API https://api.art.rmngp.fr/v1/ with nodejs.

Comment: links are broken. please validate it.

Comment: This is the elasticsearch documentation for using `javascript/nodejs` => https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html 
Use it together with `elasticsearch` module.

Comment: Thank you @SilvanBregy my issue with that documentation is that It goes into detail on how to set up an elastic search instance where you create your own DB. I want to consume that API. I'm I missing something?

Comment: @Marcelo Checkout subpoint `API Reference` =>https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html
I used it once for a private project and hat to first learn basic elastic search in order to  understand the javascript API .. IT takes some time to get into the spirit.